# Command for triggering jenkins is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, triggers

I'm new to python,

Below is python script for triggering the Jenkins project.

```
 '''subprocess for triggering jenkins'''
 print("Update Started 2.........subprocess for triggering jenkins.")
 #cmd2 = ['curl', c3]
 mycmd = r'start chrome/new-tab {}'.format(c3)

 n2=subprocess.Popen(mycmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

 #wait for the process to terminate
 #out, err = n2.communicate()
 #errcode = n2.returncode

 '''wait until trigger the jenkins'''
 print("Wait until trigger the jenkins..................")

 # Deadlock is happening here.
 n2.wait()
 print("Wait done.......................................")
```

it's not triggering the project,
But, When i tried in Debug mood - Deadlock is happening at this place `n2.wait()`

Below is log of the script:

```
Update Started 2.........subprocess for triggering jenkins.
Wait until trigger jenkins..................
```

**Update 1:**
When I tried by modifying..

```
n2.wait(10)
```

Below is the console printed data.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/adevaraj/Desktop/Jenkins_CVS_Testing_Apr/CVS_LOG_Compare.py", line 189, in <module>
    n2.wait(10)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1057, in wait
    raise TimeoutExpired(self.args, timeout)
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command 'start chrome/new-tab http://localhost:8080/job/P16G0804_GM_A2XX_PSS/build?token=A2XX' timed out after 10 seconds
```

**Update 2:**
Url is fetching from Excel sheet(That code is not posted here)

**Update 3:**

In this code c3 is url of the trigger from backend

Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to trigger a **Jenkins** build. How about simply using the **Jenkins** REST API.

```
import requests 
url = "http://localhost:8080/job/P16G0804_GM_A2XX_PSS/buildWithParameters? 
arg1=val1&arg2=val2"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: yes, that i given in back end excel sheet, it is fetching url from excel and triggering the same. @Sourav